# weird tomcat7 on start

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat7

My Tomcat 7 Works fine, but when i retrieve the run command, return:

```
    # ps -ef | grep java 
tomcat7  18794     1  2 09:30 ?        00:01:09 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
    -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
    -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start root     20085 18341  0 10:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java
```

I can't remove the "-Xmx128m" parameter.

I change this files:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh
/usr/share/tomcat7/defaults.template
```

But the parameter persist.

The xmx & xms are assigned correctly to 2048m, but i want a correct start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you search through this file ? :

```
/etc/default/tomcat7
```

Find the line with `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true`
and change the -Xmx128 parameter

Comment: Thx! i Solved this issue .

Answer (score 0):

Solved!.

Just edit `/etc/default/tomca7` and change this line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

to this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```